# magento2 rest api ship to name not adding after creating shipment

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, shipment

Ship to name is not adding while creating shipment using Rest Api with below api url:

http://127.0.0.1/magento225/rest/V1/shipment/

Body:

```
{
 "entity":{
   "orderId":9,
   "store_id":1,
  "items":[{"orderItemId":15,"qty":1}]
  }
}
```

please find the below screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer myself:

Its working fine with below Api:

http://127.0.0.1/magento225/rest/V1/order/order_id/ship

Body:

```
{
 "entity":{
   "store_id":1,
  "items":[{"orderItemId":19,"qty":1}]
  },
  "tracks": [
    {
      "track_number": "1Y-9876543210",
      "title": "Custom",
      "carrier_code": "SomeCarrierCode"
    }
  ]
}
```